# How to hide the authorization header with bearer authentication in our http site for security reasons?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, axios

Currently I have set my axios headers & the client user has access to that from the browser network tab headers. So I tested it with postman application and user can modify the data easily and manipulate many changes in our network. I need your suggestions in either hiding the authorization header in browser or some alternative approach to more secure authentication than bearer authentication. I have tried deleting the header itself but it ends in an 401 error.

```
const getCategories = () => {
  var encodedURI = encodeURI(categoryEndpoint);
  return axios.get(encodedURI, {headers:{Authorization:"auth token value","x-api-key":"api key","Content-Type":""});
};
```

I have used TransformRequest to delete the header but ended up in an 401 error.

Comment: The bearer token should just identify the user.  Your server side code should check if that user is allowed to perform that operation before the operation happens.

Comment: @James admin ID has access to everything in the application, User can also get and post new data right?

Comment: Does each user have their own credentials/token?